# Windows Popup appears while saving data in Chrome

Tags: selenium-webdriver, browser

I am creating some data and click on Save button. Manually when i do it there is no popup at all. But in automation browser of chrome i could see a popup appears asking to stay in page or leave page. How can i avoid the popup in automation script?

As per my knowledge, we have to create profile for chrome driver. I used the below whicc is not working for me. Can someone plssss plssss help me out on this

```
        String userProfile= "C:\\Users\\user_name\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\";
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("user-data-dir="+userProfile);
        options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: There are 2 different question here. Do you simply want to open `http://www.google.com` or you want to open `http://www.google.com` with specific userprofile? To open `http://www.google.com` you dont need to use any specific userprofile. We can handle the popups through option class.

Comment: I have mentioned the URL just for reference. In my application, there is a scenario where i save some data after filling the details. In normal browser i am not seeing any popups. Where in automation browser i could see the popups (as mentioned Leave Page or Stay page buttons appears)
@apurv-chatterjee. Pls refer the above description

Comment: The solution depends on the type of pop-up you are observing. There are a different types of popups &  different approach to handle them. Can you provide a snapshot of the pop-up which you want to handle?

Answer (score 0):

is there any specific reason that you are using `ChormeOptions`?

You can simply use the below code, and it'll work fine and no popups.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","pathToChromeDriver");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```